# Algo to find duplicates in a very large array

Tags: javascript, java, python, c, algorithm

During one of technical interview got this question.
I know way to solve this problem using (in java) HashSet.

But i could not understand when interviewer forced on the word "**a very large array let's say 10 million elements in the given array**".

Do i need to change the approach? If not, what should be the efficient to achieve this?

PS: Algo or implementation is language agnostic.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to remove the duplicated when you find them or do you have to print them?

Comment: What he meant by `a very large array let's say 10 million elements in the given array` is that you cannot hold them in memory. The size of the is more and memory size is less.

Comment: In Python you could use `collections.Counter` no algorithm needed: `from collections import Counter; c = Counter(<array>)` all counts greater than 1 are duplicates.

Comment: @Joe, interviewer statement was "Find the duplicate integers in large array". What he wanted, find all those duplicates and number of occurrences. Possibly holding index value can help more, i think.

Comment: @Abhishek thank you for the explanation. Can u pls let us know how to deal with this, i mean what kind of data structure to use an/or algorithm?

Comment: @Sam I have provided you the steps for solving the problem. The Data structure is `Heap` and Algorithm is `Heap Sort`.

Comment: The interview is trying to gauge your problem solving skills and to see if you know what you are talking about. They may have been looking for a disk based solution. Just ask some questions about the question.

Comment: @abhishekbafna Got you.. Thanks for nice explanation. Really appreciate.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for the good suggestion.

Comment: Counter initializer would only be O(n) complexity.

Comment: If the problem and the solution sought is `language agnostic`, tag `language-agnostic` instead of enumeration programming language tags.

Comment: @greybeard I just said language agnostic to get idea of algorithm from all developers (either Java, C, Python etc.). Though i will take care of this in future. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that O-notation doesn't necessarily tell you what algorithm is fastest.  If one algorithm is O(n log n) and another algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup>), then there is *some* value *M* such that the first algorithm is faster for all n > *M*.  But *M* could be much larger than the amount of data you'll ever have to deal with.

The reason I'm bringing this up is that I think a `HashSet` is probably still the best answer, although I'd have to profile it to find out for sure.  Assuming that you aren't allowed to set up a hash table with 10 million buckets, you may still be able to set up a reasonable-sized table.  Say you can create a `HashSet` with table size 100,000.  The buckets will then be sets of objects.  If *n* is the size of the array, the average bucket size will be *n* / 100000.  So to see if an element is already in the `HashSet`, and add it if not, will take a fixed amount of time to compute the hash value, and O(*n*) to search the elements in the bucket if they're stored in a linear list(*).  Technically, this means that the algorithm to find all duplicates is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).  But since one of the *n*'s in *n*<sup>2</sup> is for a linear list that is so much smaller than the array size (by a factor of 100000), it seems likely to me that it will still take much less time than a O(*n* log *n*) sort, for 10 million items.  The value of *M*, the point at which the O(*n* log *n*) sort becomes faster, is likely to be much, much larger than that.  (I'm just guessing, though; to find out for certain would require some profiling.)

I'd tend to lean against using a sort anyway, because if all you need to do is find duplicates, a sort is doing more work than you need.  You shouldn't need to put the elements in order, just to find duplicates.  That to me suggests that a sort is not likely to be the best answer.

(*) Note that in Java 8, the elements in each bucket will be in some kind of search tree, probably a red-black tree, instead of in a linear list.  So the algorithm will still be O(*n* log *n*), and still probably lots faster than a sort.

Answer (score 5):

There were some key things, which interviewer expected you to ask back like: if you can not load the array in memory, then `how much I can load`. These are the steps to solve the problem:

1. you need to divide the array in how much memory is available to you.
2. Let's say you can load 1M number at a time. You have split the data in `k parts`. You load the first 1M and build `Min Heap` of it. Then remove the top and apply the Heapify on `Min Heap`.
3. Repeat the same for other parts of the data.
4. Now you will have K sorted splits.
5. Now fetch a first number from each K split and again build a `Min Heap`.
6. Now remove the top from the `Min Heap` and store the value in `temporary variable` as well for comparing with the next coming number for finding the duplicates.
7. Now fetch the next number from the same split (part) whose number got removed last time. Put that number on top of `Min Heap` and apply Heapify.
8. Now the top of the `Min Heap` is your next sorted number and compare it with the `temporary variable for finding the duplicates. Update the`temporary variable` if number is not duplicate.

Comment: Yes, no matter what the interviewer is seeking, the `how much can I load?` question can only be viewed favorably.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in O(nlog(n)):

- Sort the array
- find the duplicates (they will be next to each other) in one pass.

I think that is what the interviewer wanted to hear.

if you did a merge sort or a quick sort, finding the duplicates could be done at merging in hidden time.
These can be implemented "in-place", or "by-part" if the array is too large to fit in memory.

Comment: The size of the data is more then what memory is available to you. Merge sort again require extra memory of same size, So merge sort is not the answer.

Comment: Assumes the objects are orderable vs. just having equality defined. If the the objects are hashable then you can do this in 1 pass by creating a hashmap or dictionary.

Comment: We don't know that abhishek, you are speculating here. Yes achampion, but this is what the op proposed during interview and that did not seem to satisfy the interviewer.

Answer (score 1):

In short you have to find out all unique elements from array

So you can create an object and add each element from array as a property of object.

```
function uniqueArray(arr){
    var length = arr. length,
        uniqueElementArray = [];
    while(length >= 0){
        obj [arr[length]] = true;
        length-- ;

    }

    for(var i in obj){
       uniqueElementArray.push[i];
    }
    return uniqueElementArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that the very large array could fit into memory but leaving little addition memory (i.e. another data structure of similar size to the array) to play with then with some assumptions you can do this in O(n) time and in place with no additional memory.
Assumption 1: all the values in array: 0 <= value < array length (10,000,000)
Assumption 2: you can modify the array

```
>>> arr = [3, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1]
>>> for i, v in enumerate(arr):
>>>     while arr[v] != arr[i]:
>>>         arr[i], arr[v] = arr[v], arr[i]
>>>         v = arr[i]
>>> arr
[3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1]
```

Duplicates are in positions where the value doesn't equal the index.

```
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(arr) if i != v]
[3, 4, 3, 1]
```